# Unable to deseralize JSON

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

Im trying simply to deserialize a JSON payload using the JavaScriptSerializer class and running into an issue of the class property im setting this supposed deserialized data too being 'null'.

JSON:

```
{
  "XmlPayload": "<PaperLessTimeSheetActivation xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns=\"http://host.adp.com\"><iSIClientID>99783971</iSIClientID><organizationId>FDGFGD</organizationId><statusDescription>Success</statusDescription></PaperLessTimeSheetActivation>"
}
```

Here my code:

```
var jsObject = new JavaScriptSerializer();

string holdData = xmlPayload.ToString();

//*****issue: JSON XmlPayLoadConvert property is 'null'.
JSONConverted objectToConvert = jsObject.Deserialize<JSONConverted>(holdData);

string stringXDoc = ConvertToXDoc(objectToConvert.XmlPayloadToConvert);
```

Here the class the deserialized data should map too:

```
public class JSONConverted
{
    public string XmlPayloadToConvert
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: what does `xmlPayload.ToString()` contains?

Comment: well, what was the input json ? Also: should I be concerned by `xmlPayload` vs json ?

Comment: as an example: if I use the input: `string xmlPayload = "{xmlPayloadToConvert:\"awesomez\"}";`, then it works *just fine*

Comment: why do you need a ToString() method? Try without tostring. jsObject.Deserialize<JSONConverted>(xmlPayload);

Comment: @MarcGravell Ive added my JSON Marc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the edit the error becomes obvious: `XmlPayload` is not the same as `XmlPayloadToConvert`.

Change your type to:

```
public class JSONConverted
{
    public string XmlPayload {get;set;}
}
```

and it'll work fine. With some serializers (Json.NET, for example) you can also tell it how to map the names:

```
[DataContract]
public class JSONConverted
{
    [DataMember(Name = "XmlPayload") ]
    public string XmlPayloadToConvert {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: That was exactly the problem thanks Marc......This will teach me to make sure my method names are the same when using a JSON to c# class generator! I will accept your answer when I can.